# Enabling Multi-factor Authentication (MFA) for a specific application in Auth0 dashboard

Tags: auth0, multi-factor-authentication

I have multiple node.js applications on my Auth0 dashboard, and I'm trying to implement Multi-factor Authentication (MFA) for only one of them. However, in the Auth0 dashboard, I can only find the option to enable MFA for all applications.

Is there a way to enable MFA for a specific application without affecting others? I want to have MFA active only for a particular app on my Auth0 dashboard. Any guidance or steps on achieving this would be greatly appreciated.

Additionally, I have attached a screenshot of the message displayed by Auth0 when attempting to activate the MFA option.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. You can achieve this by using `Actions`. Follow those steps.

1. Go to `Actions -> Library -> Click on "Create Action Button" -> Select "Build from scratch"`
2. Give a name to the action. The trigger should be selected as "Login / Post Login". Then click on the Create button.
3. Empty all codes in the script. Then paste this line.

```
/**
* Handler that will be called during the execution of a PostLogin flow.
*
* @param {Event} event - Details about the user and the context in which they are logging in.
* @param {PostLoginAPI} api - Interface whose methods can be used to change the behavior of the login.
*/
exports.onExecutePostLogin = async (event, api) => {
  if (event.client.client_id === '<Application_Client_ID>') {
     api.multifactor.enable("any", { allowRememberBrowser: false });
  } else {
    api.multifactor.enable("none");
  }
};
```

`event.client.client_id` line allowed you to read the application client ID. You can enable MFAs for specific applications through that. Using `else` you can disable MFA for other applications.

After the configuration click on the deploy button.

1. After that, go to `Actions -> Flows -> Click on "Login" card`
2. Then on the right side click on the custom tab.
3. Drag your deployed script can and drop between the start and completed label.
4. Click on the Apply button

### Note

You need to change your MFA setting like the one below to get a better experience and bugs bugs-free environment

1. Go to `Security -> Multi-factor Auth.`
2. Follow the same as the screenshots

[image]
[image]

Auth0 Docs

- [Write Your First Action](https://auth0.com/docs/customize/actions/write-your-first-action)
- [Actions Triggers: post-login - Event Object](https://auth0.com/docs/customize/actions/flows-and-triggers/login-flow/event-object)

Let me know if you need any further assist

**Further Notes**

---

**Error -:** `BadRequestError: invalid_request (No confirmed authenticators for the enabled factors)`

**Possible fix -:**

Go to `Authentication -> authentication Profile -> Select Identifier + Password`.

If the error further persists, go to `Branding -> Universal Login -> Advance Options -> Click on Login tab -> Turn off custom login page`

If the error still there, go to `Dashboard > Security > Multi-factor Auth and enable the Email toggle (It is not always the email. It should be your preferred option. OP's perspective it was the Guardian option)`

Comment: Thank you @Kalana for your detailed response! I followed your steps, but unfortunately, I'm encountering an error:

_BadRequestError: invalid_request (No confirmed authenticators for the enabled factors)
at ResponseContext.callback (\node_modules\express-openid-connect\lib\context.js:366:15)
at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)_

I tried replacing `api.multifactor.enable("any", { allowRememberBrowser: false });` with `api.multifactor.enable("any", { allowRememberBrowser: false });` but I still get an error in both cases.

Comment: @ZCH I have updated my answer. Can you kindly try that out and provide me the outcome?

Comment: Thank you again @Kalana. The error persists. It was already configured as you suggest in the Possible fix.

Comment: @ZCH Can you try this  Dashboard > Security > Multi-factor Auth and enable the Email toggle. Let me know the result

Comment: I tried enabling the Guardian option, and it worked very well. Thank you very much for your help!